# jQuery change hover to click

Tags: jquery, hover, click, html-lists

I altered the following code and replaced .hover with .click.  Everything is working fine except the lack of an "offclick" function.  With .hover it was no issue.  How do I add to this to account for clicking off the element.  ul visibility should be 'hidden' when clicking off, outside, etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if($("ul.dropdown").length) {
    $("ul.dropdown li").dropdown();
}

});

$.fn.dropdown = function() {

return this.each(function() {

    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("click");
        $('> .dir',this).addClass("open");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    },function(){
        $(this).removeClass("click");
        $('.open',this).removeClass("open");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });

});

}
```

Comment: There is no offclick function

Comment: if someone resolve you problem, mark his question as a decision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hover` event has actually two states, in other words, for the `hover` event there are two different events are used behind the scene and these are `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` so when you hover over an element the `mouseenter` event gets fired and on hovering off the element the `mouseleave` event gets fired, so in this case, you can't convert this event to `click` using two methods like `hover` instead, you just declare one `click` event handler (function) for that element. For example, you may do something like this:

```
$('#element').on('click', function(e){
    //...
});
```

If you want to change the state of the element when another element gets clicked then you should catch the click event for that element so clicking on tnother element you may do the opposite thing. For example, you may register a click event on `$('body')` so when click happens on the `body` then you may do the opposite thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `.toggle()` for this.

```
$(SELECTOR).toggle(function () {
    // State 1
}, function () {
    // State 2
});
```

[jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how can you check that user clicked outside

```
$(document).click(function () {
    //hide ul there 
});


$(this).click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); // this forbid parent clicks (on document)
    $(this).addClass("click");
    $('> .dir',this).addClass("open");
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```